# VSCode debugger wont attach with Launch via NPM

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

Im sure this is super simple but I cant seem to get the debugger going with the Launch via NPM vscode template. I have a really simple hello world with an npm script to run the app.

If I run `Launch Program` (the config that uses just node) everything works perfectly, however if I use `Launch via NPM` I get

> /Users/luke/.nvm/versions/node/v6.5.0/bin/npm --debug-brk=3837 run-script runit
>
> hello-world@1.0.0 runit /Users/luke/source/playground/js/hello-world
>
> node index.js
>
> hello world

And no breakpoints are hit. (Ive also tried with and without `"protocol":"legacy"`)

**What am I doing wrong, all the online examples suggest that this should justworkTM.**

package.json

```
{
  "name": "hello-world",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "runit": "node index.js"
  }
}
```

launch.json:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch via NPM",
        "runtimeExecutable": "npm",
        "protocol":"legacy",
        "runtimeArgs": [
            "run-script",
            "runit"
        ]
    },
    {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch Program",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/index.js"
    }
  ]
}
```

index.js

```
console.log('hello world');//with a breakpoint set here
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok I worked it out...

Launch via NPM requires you to add some extra args into the actual NPM script:

```
{
  "name": "hello-world",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "runit": "node --nolazy --debug-brk=5858 index.js"
  }
}
```