# "Launch via NPM" configuration doesn't work in VSCode (after research)

Tags: node.js, npm, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

## Problem

I'm working with environment variables on a NodeJS project using VSCode.
I want to optimize my workflow using `.vscode/launch.json` with a *Launch via NPM* configuration.
I firstly followed [this article](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/heres-how-you-can-actually-use-node-environment-variables-8fdf98f53a0a) which explained which configuration to choose.

Here is my actual configuration which doesn't work :

```
.
├── .vscode
│   └── launch.json
├── .env
├── server.js
├── package.json
// other stuff…
```

#### The `launch.json` file

```
"configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch via NPM",
      "runtimeExecutable": "npm",
      "runtimeArgs": [
        "start"
      ],
      "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env"
    },
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Program",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/server.js",
      "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env"
    }
]
```

#### The `.env` file

```
NODE_ENV='dev'
```

#### The `server.js` file

```js
// some stuff
console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV)
```

#### The `package.json` file

```
{
  "name": "server Node",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node --inspect server.js"
  },
// dependencies and more
}
}
```

When I run `npm start` I have an `Undefined` output on the terminal.

### Other attempts

I read the [nodejs debugging documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_launch-configuration-attributes) on VSCode website, so

- I tried to add "protocol"="inspector" in my `launch.json` configuration
- I also tried to add port=9229 with `--inspect-brk=9229` on my `package.json` start script which end up with no output at all on the terminal neither on the output or the debug console. (Can't understand why again…)

And finally I read a few stack**overflow** questions with no additional information. ([this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46597313/vscode-debugger-wont-attach-with-launch-via-npm), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53352303/how-to-debug-a-nodemon-project-in-vscode) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34835082/how-to-debug-using-npm-run-scripts-from-vscode))
I'm lost, I really can't find *why* my configuration doesn't work.

look forward to seeing your next answers and finally **understand** what's wrong with the configuration I have.

> When I launch the debugger from **VSCode**, the terminal outputs `dev`. So it isn't a path or *deeper* configuration problem. Well, I think…

## Environment

VS Code : `Version 1.30.2`
node : `11.6.0`

Comment: I didn't have any luck using "launch" for debugging a running Express JS app. It only worked for me for running files. However, this worked for me for a running app, using "attach" instead of "launch": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37321872/debug-expressjs-server-side-code-using-visual-studio-code